# Is the Provider Model using the Factory pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, provider-model

Is the Provider Model really just the Factory pattern?

Comment: do you mean this "provider model"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model),

> Providers are a subclass of the ProviderBase class and typically instantiated using a factory method.

So I would say no, they're not same thing, but a factory is used in implementing a Provider.

You can also follow [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx) and Ctrl-F for "factory" to see how the pattern is used in the provider model.